# Trying to reshape a data frame for upload to a Google Big Query Table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, google-bigquery

I have data that looks like this;

```
Raw_Title   Custom_Field
Manager Ben
Manager Ron
Manager Liz
Severity    4 - Low
Severity    2 - High
Severity    1 - Urgent
Type of Dataset Private
Type of Dataset Public
Type of Dataset Public
Request Category    Company :: Add
Request Category    User :: Add User
Request Category    User :: Remove User
Incident Category   Pipeline :: Cloud
Incident Category   UI :: Other
Incident Category   UI :: Authentication
Platform Environment    Staging
Platform Environment    Development
Platform Environment    Production
```

I am trying to reshape it into this:

```
Manager Severity    Type of Dataset Request Category    Incident Category   Platform Environment
Ben 4 - Low Private Company :: Add  Pipeline :: Cloud   Staging
Ron 2 - High    Public  User :: Add User    UI :: Other Development
Liz 1 - Urgent  Public  User :: Remove User UI :: Authentication    Production
```

I thought the solution would be like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(filtered_df, columns = ['Manager','Severity','Type of Dataset','Request Category  ','Incident Category','Platform Environment'])
print(df)
```

However that gives me a completely empty data frame!!

All I want to do is take the 'Raw_Title' and pivot it from rows to columns, and then list the data points in 'Custom_Field' under each respective 'Raw_Title'.  How can I do that?  I have to get it into this format so I can export everything to a Google Big Query table.  Thanks for the look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the dataframe pivot to do that

[Dataframe Pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Raw_Title': ['Manager','Manager','Manager','Severity','Severity','Severity',
                    'Type of Dataset','Type of Dataset','Type of Dataset',
                    'Request Category','Request Category','Request Category',
                    'Incident Category','Incident Category','Incident Category','Platform Environment',
                    'Platform Environment','Platform Environment'],
                   'Custom_Field': ['Ben','Ron','Liz',
                       '4 - Low','2 - High','1 - Urgent',
                       'Private','Public','Public','Company :: Add',
                       'User :: Add User','User :: Remove User',
                       'Pipeline :: Cloud','UI :: Other','UI :: Authentication',
                       'Staging','Development','Production']})

dfPivoted = df.pivot(columns='Raw_Title', values='Custom_Field')
```

The resulting dataframe will have nulls for every column where the row didn't have that column's data type. If you have a identifier that links the rows together, use that for the index (index=)

Comment: Thanks.  This seems to work fine.  The only thing is, I was looking for a more dynamic solution.  So, I wanted to just list field names, like I'm showing in the second image, and get the data points to fill down, so all rows are populated.  It looks like your solution works, but I can't manually type in all data points each time I run this.  This is a pull from a data base, I'm using Python to transform the data and load it into another database.

Comment: I only manually typed them because I don't have access to your database. As long as your data is in a dataframe with those column names, the ".pivot" function will work